How to pick initial values for Shor's algorithm?
From my understanding Shor's algorithm can be summarised as follows...
Task: given a positive integer $N$ find another positive integer $s$ such that $s$ divides $N$.
Steps (informal)

Choose an integer $a$ uniformly at random from the interval $[1, N]$
Compute $b = \gcd(a, N)$. If $b > 1$, then $b$ divides $N$. Otherwise continue to 3.
Determine the period of the function $f(x) = a^x \,\text{mod} \,N$. In other words, find the least positive integer $r$ such that $f(x+r)=f(x)$. Note that this is the part that uses the quantum computer. This is typically done with quantum phase estimation.
Now if $a^{r/2}$ is an integer evaluate $s=\gcd(a^{r/2}-1, N)$. If $a^{r/2}$ is not an integer our algorithm fails. Likewise if $s=1$, our algorithm hasn't worked and we try need to try again. If $s \neq 1$, then $s$ is a factor of $N$ and our algorithm has worked.

Note that the steps above give you a single non-trivial factor of $N$. In the textbook version of Shor's algorithm, we usually have to repeat the above to get all the factors of $N$.
My question is mostly about step 1 where we choose $a$.
A key part of the algorithm is this difference of two squares factorisation.
$$
a^r -1 = (a^{r/2} -1)(a^{r/2} + 1) = 0 \,\, \text{mod} \, N
$$
Now if $a^{r/2}$ is not an integer, then we're in trouble as $\gcd(a^{r/2}-1, N)$ is not defined. This is usually the case when our quantum computer gives us an odd number for the period $r$. However in the edge case where $r$ is odd but $a$ is a perfect square the algorithm can still succeed. This is becuase if $a=j^2$ for some positive integer $j$,  then $a^{r/2}=(j^2)^{r/2} =j^r$.
I'm asking the following... What is the reason for choosing $a$ uniformly at random from the positive integers less than $N$? Have people considered other distributions from which to sample $a$?
A trivial way to choose $a$ would be to sample from the set of all of the perfect squares  less than $N$. This would mean that $a^{r/2}$ is always an integer regardless of the value of the period $r$. Surely it cannot be this simple and I must have misunderstood something or missed some other requirements for the algorithm to succeed. Perhaps sampling from contrived distributions makes it less likely to find non-trivial factors of $N$? I'm not sure.
Example
Consider the basic example of factoring $N=21$. Suppose our random choice in step 1. gives us $a=4$.
Now we have to determine the period of the function $f(x) = 4^x \, \text{mod} \, 21$. We can determine that the period is $r=3$ by evaluating $f(x)$ on a range of inputs.
Now normally the fact that $r$ is odd would cause problems. However in this case $a^{r/2}=4^{3/2}=8$ (an integer as $4$ is a perfect square).
Now we see that $\gcd(a^{r/2}-1,\, N)=\gcd(7,\, 21)=7$. Clearly $7$ divides $21$. So we have found that $21 = 7 \times 3$.

+1 but you can use \gcd for gcd - looks better.

Cool, thanks :) made the edit

is there an efficient way to sample from the set of perfect squares less than $N$?

@gIS what is wrong with sampling $b$ UAR from $[1,2,\cdots,\sqrt N]$ and then letting $a=b^2$?

@MarkSpinelli does that result in a uniform distribution on the $b^2$ though? Eg sampling uniformly $x$ from $[0,1]$ and computing $x^2$ gives the non-uniform pdf $p_{X^2}(x)=p_X(\sqrt x)/2\sqrt x$. Granted, I have no idea whether having a non-uniform distribution on the $b^2$ is at all problematic here

A natural thing to do, rather than choosing an actual perfect square, would be to choose a random quadratic residue by selecting $b\in\mathbb{Z}_N^{\ast}$ uniformly and then take $a = b^2 \pmod{N}.$

However, I don't believe this particular modification helps. Suppose we choose $b\in\mathbb{Z}_N^{\ast}$ somehow and take $a = b^2 \pmod{N}.$ If $r$ is the order of $b$ modulo $N,$ and $r$ happens to be odd, then $b^2$ also has order $r$ modulo $N,$ while if $r$ is even, then $b^2$ has order $r/2.$ This means that we don't learn anything new by computing the order of $b^2$ as compared with computing the order of $b.$ In particular, if $r$ is odd, we would by this method compute $(b^2)^{r/2} = b^r = 1 \pmod{N}$ and fail to find a factor of $N.$

With regard to the example provided in the question, yes, we can find a factor of 21 when $a = 4,$ which has order $r = 3$ by computing $4^{3/2} = 8.$ But we would get the same factor by taking the square root before computing the order. What I'm suggesting is that purposely choosing a square and computing the order is no better than computing the order without squaring.

Ah thanks, I think I see your point. If we choose $a=2$ instead then the period of $f(x)= 2^x , \text{mod} , 21$ is $r=6$ so we still get the same value for $a^{r/2}$ namely 8. I suppose this is generally true?

Leander's work is somewhat related to the above discussion, see [Leander02]. For a survey of other earlier ideas for improving the classical post-processing, see e.g. Sect. 2 in [E21b].

@Callum In your step 3, it would be good to state that $r$ is the least positive integer that meets the requirement (so that $r$ is the order of $a$ in $\mathbb Z_N^*$).

Good point. I will edit, thanks.

Shor proves in [Shor94] [Shor97] that if $N$ is a positive odd integer that has $k \ge 2$ distinct prime factors, and if $a$ is selected uniformly at random from $\mathbb Z_N^*$ as in your steps 1–2, then the probability that the order $r$ of $a$ is even and that $a^{r/2} \not\equiv -1 \:\: (\text{mod } N)$ is at least $1 - 2^{1-k} \ge 1/2$.
The uniform selection of $a$ from $\mathbb Z_N^*$ greatly facilitates the derivation of said proof.
In practice, it is possible to select $a$ in other ways, but depending on how $a$ is selected it may then be considerably more difficult to prove that the algorithm works for general $N$. In the literature, there are examples of people considering other ways of selecting $a$ for special-form $N$. One such example that comes to mind is [GLMS15].
Another example, that is somewhat related to the discussion in the comments on your question, is [Leander02].
The above having been said, note also that by replacing your step 4 with a slightly more advanced classical post-processing step, it is possible to guarantee finding the complete factorization of $N$ with probability very close to one, see my work [E21b] (and also my work [E24] for the complete algorithm in your steps 1–4). In short, with a uniform selection of $a$ from $\mathbb Z_N^*$, we expect to have to run the quantum order-finding part only once to completely factor $N$ into all of its prime factors. There is no need for special treatment of odd $r$, etc.

Thank you @Martin Ekera for your thorough answer. I will take a look at the references.

I came across the bound you stated before. I suppose you could try and beat $\geq 1/2$ but as you pointed out if we try another distribution it may be more challenging to prove correctness of the algorithm for all $N$. This is good enough in practice. Also very interesting to hear that you can get all of the factors of $N$ with a single use of the quantum order finding subroutine too.

Hey Martin, thanks for a great answer! Can you add a short disclosure that you're the author of some of the papers you linked please? Thanks!

@Tristan Nemoz Sure, I can do that. I thought it was clear from the naming convention, and  the works themselves.

@Callum Sure. In short, to achieve a very high success probability, the key as I see it is to modify the post-processing rather than to modify the selection of $a$.
